# Where in Kusatsu, Japan are this bridge, runnel and lily pads?

Tags: japan, identify-this

[This Reddit post](https://redd.it/bsizfp) asseverates [Kusatsu](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Kusatsu,+Agatsuma+District,+Gunma,+Japan/@36.6100592,138.5082009,12z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x601de7cae803dfe9:0xfd7719d95b1f956b!8m2!3d36.6207181!4d138.5960945) Japan, but what's the address?

[image]

Comment: #TIL: asseverates. I was going to edit that as a typo until I looked it up.

Comment: @FreeMan You and me both. And my girl-friend (and she is a professional translator) had never heard of it either. It's been years since either of us encountered an English word we didn't already know.

Comment: It's like a mashup of *assert* and *aver*.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This appears to be the [Mizunomori Water Botanical Garden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mizunomori_Water_Botanical_Garden).  A very similar photo to yours can be seen [here](https://www.shiga.love/en/mizunomori/).  It is [apparently](https://en.biwako-visitors.jp/spot/detail/22) located at 1091 Oroshimo-cho, Kusatsu City, Shiga.

(Note that your Google Maps link is not pointing to the [city of Kusatsu in Shiga Prefecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kusatsu,_Shiga), but to [a different and much smaller town named Kusatsu in Gunma Prefecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kusatsu,_Gunma).)

Comment: Thanks!  have you been there? if not, how did you figure out the location?

Comment: @MatthewLau: I have not been there.  I just did a bunch of searches for "Kusatsu gardens" and things like that.